# How do I speed up a video by 60X in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, speed

I found this example

```
 ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output.mkv
```

but I have a video I want to speed up by 60 times, not just 2X.

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Simply multiply by the reciprocal of the speed factor.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/60" output.mkv
```

This does not affect the audio speed. Use `-an` to not include audio in the output.

---

A faster method, but which can have unexpected results with audio (pauses or async):

```
ffmpeg -itsscale 0.01666 -i input.mkv -c copy output.mkv
```

where `0.01666` is `1/60` in decimal representation.

Comment: While the playback speed seems to be changed for this, the video duration seems to be represented incorrectly; e.g., a 3 minute video sped up 3x will still show as being 3 minutes long. If you play it in a video player (e.g., VLC) the video will only take up the first minute and then freeze on a frame for the remaining 2 minutes.

Comment: Does it have audio?

Comment: It does make sense that ffmpeg would leave the full length of the video because there was still audio data. Good catch, it turns out, it did have audio (my speakers were muted). With the `-an` parameter, the length of the video is set properly.

Comment: this is too slow. for me it's encoding 2 frames/second.  i've got about 30 minutes of video!

Comment: See new method.

Comment: The second method is creating a file around 99.99% the size of the input with 60% of the duration - when I play it, I see each individual frame rendered for several seconds.  Both with and without `-an` (although I'm not sure exactly where it's supposed to go)

Comment: Ok, so correct me if I'm wrong, but the second method is faster because it doesn't actually do anything - the whole video is still there, just with metadata that is instructing the player to play it at an impossibly fast rate. (Which quite honestly, is useless and not what i was expecting)

Comment: Yes, video playback speed is governed by packet metadata. 60x is a very high speed up and players will usually choke. You'll see more expected results with, say, a 6x speed up. Players can't "skip" frames in a compressed video bitstream since almost all frames depend on one or more surrounding frames for decoding. So, you have to drop frames and re-encode i.e. a timelapse, e.g. `ffmpeg -i input -vf framestep=60,setpts=N/30/TB -r 30 -an out.mp4`

Comment: There's a large difference in these two methods in terms of file size, at least for my specific movie. The former outputs a video that's ~100x smaller, while the latter outputs a file that's the same size as the original.

Comment: Yes, the latter keeps all frames since it is copying the stream and only changes their timestamps. The former changes all timestamps but the frame rate control logic which is applied later during re-encoding drops frames closer in time than given frame rate.

Comment: @Michael it outputs 2 fps of the *new video*, which is 120 fps of the original video.

Comment: I used this to correct a faulty bad PowerPoint 41-second screen recording reducing a 400MB file, 41-minute file to a 400K file, 41-second file (1000:1 reduction in file size, and a 60:1 reduction in playback speed). `ffmpeg -y -i bad-powerpoint.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/60" -an -r 1 fast.mp4`

Answer (score 46):

If you also want to speed up the audio, you need to do this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Docs: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

The command above works if you want to multiply by 2 the speed. If you want to multiply by any `x` (between 0 and 100), the parameters become:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=1/<x>*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=<x>[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

For instance, if you want to multiply by 1.15, the command is

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Comment: atempo has a range 0 to 2. can't be any x.

Comment: atempo now has a range up to 100: https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=29cddc99cd8302e462bbae572e885e88f63d6dc3

Comment: How can we speed up a specific portion of the video given a time range??

Comment: the easiest would be splitting the video into chunks, speeding up the desired chunk and stitching them back together

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to speed up video with audio using ffmpeg, without changing audio pitch?](https://superuser.com/q/1324525/53514)

Comment: You can leave math expressions in, no need to calculate them yourself, eg 1/1.15 is fine. I would prefer the non-complex filter option: `-vf "setpts=2*PTS" -af "atempo=1/2"`, this way you can use the same command regardless of whether audio is present or not. Also, this will drop frames to slow down a video, you can prevent this by setting a framerate with `-r`.

Comment: My zsh alias: `alias ffmpeg_speed='(){ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "$2" -vf "setpts=1/($1)*PTS" -af "atempo=$1" -r 60 "$3" ;}'`

Answer (score 9):

For a stop-motion project where I wanted to reduce the delay between frames (instead of dropping frames), I wanted to speed up the audio and video many times beyond 2x too. For 60x speed, do the following. It may be a bit verbose, but it works great. The problem is that atempo cannot be greater than two or less than 0.5, so we must repeat atempo many times to get the sound to the rate that we want it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/60" -filter:a "atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=1.875" output.mkv
```

Press Ctrl+Shift+I, and click the "console" tab. In the console, to start typing/pasting text, click in the whitespace just right of the blue horizontal chevron (double chevron in FireFox). In Firefox, type `allow pasting` into the console to allow copy'n'paste, then Ctrl+A then backspace to remove that text. Then, copy and paste this code into the console and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run. The code also works with slowing down the video.

```
var speed=eval(prompt("Enter speed up or slowdown factor (>1 is speedup, " +
    "<1 is slowdown; can use 1/X for slowdown): ", "60"));

var k=speed, audio="";
while (2 < k && k === k) k /= 2, audio+="atempo=2,";
while (k < 0.5 && k === k) k *= 2, audio+="atempo=0.5,";
audio += "atempo=" + k;
prompt(
    "Copy the following commandline: ",
    'ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/' + speed +
    '" -filter:a "' + audio + '" output.mkv'
);
```

This code will prompt you to enter a value and present you with the result. Entering `60` yields a 60X speedup, entering `0.1` yields a 10X slowdown, and entering `1/30` yields a 30X slowdown. I hope this helps.

Comment: From another comment on a different answer, atempo now can be up to 100: https://git.videolan.org/gitweb.cgi/ffmpeg.git/?a=commit;h=29cddc99cd8302e462bbae572e885e88f63d6dc3

Answer (score 9):

##### Speed up by 60x, with 60x the original fps

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/60" -an output.mkv
```

- `setpts=PTS/60` divides each frame's [*presentation time-stamp*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58268695/365102) by 60.
- `-an` removes the audio.

##### Speed up by 60x, then resample to 24 fps

```bash
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "setpts=PTS/60,fps=24" -an output.mkv
```

- `setpts=PTS/60` divides each frame's [*presentation time-stamp*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58268695/365102) by 60.
- `fps=24` outputs 24 frames per second.
- `-an` removes the audio.

Comment: this answer is very helpful, as my goal was to speed up and compress at the same time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For me, using `setpts` in conjunction with `atempo` left the audio rate low (and with low pitch).
What finally worked for me is:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# Note: First use ffprobe to get the audio rate.
# Adjust below if it's not 48000.
# The example below increases the speed of audio and video
# rate by a factor of 4 (adjust as needed).
# Sources:
# https://superuser.com/questions/1261678/how-do-i-speed-up-a-video-by-60x-in-ffmpeg
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374590/ffmpeg-change-tone-frequency-pitch-audio
ffmpeg -i $1 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/4" -af "asetrate=48000*4,aresample=48000" out.mp4
```

Comment: I needed to convert slow motion video from my Google Pixel phone (a Pixel 6 pro) to full "normal" speed. This is what worked.

Answer (score 1):

Only for video, like timelapses:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb raw.h264

ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -r 30 -i raw.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Comment: can you explain if both commands are needed(what each does) and what specifies the speed?

Answer (score 1):

This will only work on 4.4 and up:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -bsf:v "setts=TS/60" -af "atempo=60" -c:v copy output.mkv
```