# Is it possible to speed up video with audio using ffmpeg, without changing audio pitch?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

Is there a relatively simple way to speed up a video (mp4, with aac encoded audio), by say "x1.25" or "x1.3" while keeping the original audio-video sync, but also retaining the original pitch of the audio ?

I've read some discussions about extracting audio track into separate file, then use `rubberband` to lower the pitch by the requisite value, and then merge the audio video tracks using ffmpeg with speed-up, which raises the pitch of the audio back again to original. However, it appears that this is a bit of hit-n-miss, because `rubberband` appears to use number of octaves as the parameter to raise or lower pitch, and this may not always align perfectly with the video, as musical notes / octaves have specific ratios. Also, this is cumbersome.

So, is there any simpler ways using ffmpeg alone ?

Comment: rubberband offers a tempo option which takes in a decimal number.

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. Sounds like a valid answer, even if it is not as simple as I'd hope it to be, but removes the issue of `rubberband` being (wrongly presumed to be) limited to pitch change based on number of notes (of a chromatic scale).

Comment: rubberband can be compiled as a ffmpeg filter, so no need to extract audio.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It can be done with ffmpgeg using a complex filter:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Documentation: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

The command above works if you want to multiply by 2 the speed. If you want to multiply by any `<x>`, the parameters become:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=<1/x>*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=<x>[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

For instance, if you want to multiply by 1.15, the command is:

```
  ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.87*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.15[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv
```

Comment: if i want to slow my video and audio down by exactly half, would atempo=0.5 and setpts=1.5  ??

Comment: For half speed: atempo=0.5 and setpts=2

Comment: @Weidenrinde Why doesn't this work: [0:a]asetpts=PTS*0.5[a] ???

Comment: @RicardoBohner If I try that, I don´t receive any audio. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Weidenrinde No it doesn't but in my head it's the equivalent of [0:v]setpts=PTS*0.5[v] what works to speed up the vídeo I wonder why it doesn't work for audio the same way.

Comment: With ffmpeg version 4.4 I got the audio sped up to 1.25 but the video stayed the same length.  The answer by @sagunms did both.

Answer (score 10):

You can speed up video by 2.5X for example by doing this:

```
ffmpeg -i "input_video.mp4" -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/2.5" -af atempo=2.5 "input_video_2.5X.mp4"
```

Here is a bash script you can use for convenience (say `convert_video.sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Arguments
FILE_RAW=$1
SPEED_FACTOR=${2:-1.0} # Default is 1.0 X speed

# Prepare variables
BASE_PATH=$(dirname $(readlink -f $FILE_RAW))
FILENAME_EXT="$(basename "${FILE_RAW}")"
FILENAME_ONLY="${FILENAME_EXT%.*}"
EXT_ONLY="${FILENAME_EXT#*.}"
FILENAME_ONLY_PATH="${BASE_PATH}/${FILENAME_ONLY}"

# Speed up/slow down video
ffmpeg -i "${FILENAME_ONLY_PATH}.${EXT_ONLY}" -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/${SPEED_FACTOR}" -af atempo=$SPEED_FACTOR "${FILENAME_ONLY_PATH}_${SPEED_FACTOR}X.${EXT_ONLY}"
```

**Note:** Make script executable: `chmod +x convert_video.sh`

**Usage** (Output File: `<PATH_TO_INPUT_VIDEO>_<OPTIONAL_SPEED>X.mp4`)

```
. <PATH_TO_THIS_SCRIPT>/convert_video.sh <PATH_TO_INPUT_VIDEO> <OPTIONAL_SPEED>
```

**Example 1:** Speed up video to 2.5X (Output: `~/Videos/input_video_2.5X.mp4`)

```
. ~/convert_video.sh ~/Videos/input_video.mp4 2.5
```

**Example 2:** Slow down video to 0.5X (Output: `~/Videos/input_video_0.5X.mp4`)

```
. ~/convert_video.sh ~/Videos/input_video.mp4 0.5
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: WFM with ffmpeg version 4.4 . Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The code I used.

```
speed_change(){
    input=$1
    output=$2
    a_speed=$3
    v_speed=$(awk -v a_speed=$a_speed 'BEGIN{print 1/a_speed}')
    echo -e "\nSpeed up ${a_speed}X, para to atempo is ${a_speed}, para to setpts is ${v_speed}.\n"
    ffmpeg -i $input -c:v hevc_videotoolbox -vf "setpts=$v_speed*PTS" -af atempo=$a_speed $output
}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a little more?