# Why isn't ffmpeg making this video shorter?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm trying to double the speed of a video.

I use the commands:

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" output2.mp4
```

and

```
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -vf "setpts=0.5*PTS" output3.mp4
```

which I find all over the internet as being the standard method.

However, all my files are the same length:

```
joe@joe-Amd-Am4-Home-Office:~$ for file in *.mp4; do duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$file"); echo "$file: $duration seconds"; done
output2.mp4: 373.014000 seconds
output3.mp4: 373.014000 seconds
output.mp4: 373.014000 seconds
```

What's going on and how do I properly speed up the video?  I'm using ubuntu.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

My first guess would be that the PTS approach, documented [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), works "by changing the presentation timestamp (PTS) of each video frame," which *players* would respect and speed up. But perhaps that does not change the *reported* length of the video as `ffprobe` sees it.

But fiddling with a random test mp4 I have shows that, while the video is sped up, the audio is not. Which would explain why I too see the same timestamp for each video via `ffprobe`. This lines up with a note from the documentation linked above:

> Note that in the following examples, the audio stream is not changed, so it should ideally be disabled with `-an`.

Another answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1394709/220550) offers the following complex filter to speed up both the video and audio:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.5*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=2.0[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv`

And that one works for me, showing half of the length via `ffprobe`.

Comment: Perfect - the -an fixed it.  Also wonderfully well explained and tested.

Comment: Weird that PTS is inverse rated to atempo. This means you have to use a formula to reach the correct numbers programmatically. I love ffmpeg, but the filtergraph scheme needs a rewrite.

Comment: Note that `setpts` could be described as non-destructive, while `atempo` definitely transcodes the audio (stretch/pitch-shift). They are very different operations, which also explains why they take "inverse" numbers. They just happen to be used simultaneously in this case... so I'd say the filtergraph doesn't need a rewrite ;)