# How to speedup video with FFmpeg based on timestamps from CSV?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, csv

There are already questions with regard to speeding up a video with FFmpeg, like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1324525/is-it-possible-to-speed-up-video-with-audio-using-ffmpeg-without-changing-audio).

My question is: Is there also a way to specify multiple sections which shall be speedup via an external CSV.

My CSV looks like this:

```
start, end
00:00:03.296, 00:00:14.372,
00:00:16.388, 00:00:33.635,
00:00:33.693, 00:00:39.428,
00:00:39.460, 00:00:50.355,
00:00:50.355, 00:01:17.892,
00:01:17.892, 00:01:19.845,
00:01:19.845, 00:01:47.616,
```

These are the exact sections (one section per line, two timestamps which define start and end of each section) which shall be speed-up by 10x. The rest shall be kept original playback speed.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It is probably possible, but FFmpeg doesn't accept timestamps in CSV format. We may use a Python script for creating the command line from the CSV content. Without a script, do it manually. `setpts` filter accepts expressions. It looks like the expression is going to be quite complicated in this case.

Comment: Actually I wrote a PythonScript now - but I cant get the FFMPEG command to work exactly as I want.

The command for splitting which I use is: `ffmpeg.exe -i input-mp4 -ss 00:00:50.355 -to 00:01:17.892 -c copy -strict -2 clip_1.mp4` - it seems depending on ss and to it does not always EXACTLY as I want, but rather at specific keyframes...?!

And for accelerating clips I use: `ffmpeg.exe -i clip_1.mp4 -filter:v 'setpts=0.1*PTS' -strict -2 clip_1_acc.mp4`.

But I get a Filter error. Do you think those commands are really correct?

Comment: I posted an example for [setting PTS using PyAV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75348681/4926757). It could be a better approach. Also check the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37893746/4926757).

Answer (score 1):

We may set the desired PTS timestamp of each video frame, using [setpts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) filter with elaborated nested `if` expression.

The following answer, is just a "proof of concept", assuming you have the knowledge creating the more complex expression you need programmatically.
The solution assumes that the input video has a fixed framerate, and that it's simple to compute the input timestamp from the input frame number.

Note:
Accelerating parts of the video by setting the timestamps creates a variable framerate (VFR) video, which may not play nicely in all video players.
It may be better to create fixed framerate video by speeding up all the video by a factor of x10, and duplicate each frame 10 times in the parts of the original rate.
Note that using a Python script that reads frame with OpenCV, and writes using OpenCV (or better pipe to FFmpeg), it is relatively simple to duplicate the frames.

---

Assume we have the following input file (40 frames at 1fps):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=40 -c:v libx264 -g 1 input.mp4`

The timestamps of the input video are:

```
 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
```

Assume we want to speed in range [0, 19] and [30, 39], and get the following output timestamps:

```
 0,    1,    2,    3,    4,    5,    6,    7,    8,    9,
10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9,
11,   12,   13,   14,   15,   16,   17,   18,   19,   20,
21, 21.1, 21.2, 21.3, 21.4, 21.5, 21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 21.9,
```

We may use the following FFmpeg command:

`ffmpeg -y -r 100 -i input.mp4 -fps_mode:v passthrough -vf "setpts='(if(lt(N,10), N, if(lt(N,20), ((N-10)/10)+10, if(lt(N,30), 11+(N-20), 21+(N-30)/10))))/TB'" -c:v libx264 -g 1 output.mp4`

- `-r 100` is used for setting packet duration to 10msec (short packet duration allows higher resolution of timestamps).
- `-fps_mode:v passthrough` - passes each input frame from input to output (without duplicating the frames due to the 100 fps rate).
- `-vf "setpts='(if(lt(N,10), N, if(lt(N,20), ((N-10)/10)+10, if(lt(N,30), 11+(N-20), 21+(N-30)/10))))/TB'"` - Uses `if` expressions and some math for adjusting the timestamps.
  The `if` expression applies if(condition, value if true, value if false).
  `N` is the input frame number, start counting from zero.
  `if(lt(N,10), N, ...` sets PTS to `N` for the first 10 frames...
  `/TB` divides by the time in seconds by the time-base.
- `-g 1` - Set GOP size to 1 for testing (remove it). It keeps the PTS sorted when using FFprobe.

---

Verifying the output timestamps using FFprobe:
`ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time output.mp4`

Output is as expected:

```
pts_time=0.000000
pts_time=1.000000
pts_time=2.000000
pts_time=3.000000
pts_time=4.000000
pts_time=5.000000
pts_time=6.000000
pts_time=7.000000
pts_time=8.000000
pts_time=9.000000
pts_time=10.000000
pts_time=10.100000
pts_time=10.190000
pts_time=10.300000
pts_time=10.400000
pts_time=10.500000
pts_time=10.600000
pts_time=10.700000
pts_time=10.800000
pts_time=10.900000
pts_time=11.000000
pts_time=12.000000
pts_time=13.000000
pts_time=14.000000
pts_time=15.000000
pts_time=16.000000
pts_time=17.000000
pts_time=18.000000
pts_time=19.000000
pts_time=20.000000
pts_time=21.000000
pts_time=21.100000
pts_time=21.200000
pts_time=21.300000
pts_time=21.400000
pts_time=21.500000
pts_time=21.600000
pts_time=21.700000
pts_time=21.800000
pts_time=21.900000
```

---

Animated GIF that demonstrates the output:
[image]
(Created using `ffmpeg -y -i output.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -r 1 output.gif`)