# Set framerate of movie (mp4, no audio) without reencoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a video only (no audio) file in h264, mp4 format with 25 FPS and I would like to just set the framerate up to 30 without reencoding the video.

Source file:

```
ffprobe 25fps.mp4 
ffprobe version 4.1.4-1build2 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.2.1-4ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1build2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '25fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.96, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15858 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15854 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Expected output:

```
[...]
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '30fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:00:04.13, start: 0.000000, bitrate: (approx. 19000) kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], (approx. 19000) kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

What I could acchieve so far is either:

- creating a file with 29.86 FPS without reencoding (following this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/45465730/841033)
- creating a file with 30 FPS with reencoding (`ffmpeg -i 25fps.mp4 -r 30 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/1.2" 30fps.mp4`)

Both is not what I wanted. Any suggestions?
I thought/expected this should be as easy as "man, play this at 1.2 speed, thanx"

EDIT:
Solved as stated in the comment. Had to try some values arount `5/6` until I found it:

```
ffmpeg -itsscale 0.832 -i 25fps.mp4 -c copy 30fps.mp4
```

Comment: See 2nd method in https://superuser.com/a/1261681/

Comment: perfect. -itsscale 0.832 did it. Had to try some values arount 5/6 to get it right.