# Speeding up video and audio while doubling frame rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I have used Jack Giffin's JavaScript code from here (3rd answer) to generate an ffmpeg command to speed up a video, with the audio, by 8x.

[How do I speed up a video by 60X in ffmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/1261678/how-do-i-speed-up-a-video-by-60x-in-ffmpeg)

However, my original video is 30fps. Is there a way to get an output video with 8x speed but at 60fps, so that I'm making use of some frames that would otherwise be discarded?

My current command line is:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/8" -filter:a "atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fps filter.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter:v "setpts=PTS/8,fps=60" -filter:a "atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2" output.mp4
```

Comment: This worked, although the output video had the same length as the original video, but I can trim it to the correct length.